# Is there a path to upgrade an OEM Embedded org to a full CRM Licensed org?

Tags: isv, licenses, oem

Is there a path for a subscriber who received their org via an OEM Embedded purchase from the ISV to upgrade their OEM-provisioned environment to a full CRM licensed org?

- What does that upgrade path look like?
- Is the upgrade just purchasing Salesforce licenses to be available within the org?
- Is there additional contractual considerations?
- Is there specific terminology for this process?

If no, is the subscriber required to provision a new CRM org, then perform an install of the ISV’s app in the new org and then perform what is essentially an org migration from the original OEM Embedded org to the new one?

Comment: Could you pls. help here https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/413101/salesforce-app-exchange-oem-we-are-oem-partner-can-we-sell-our-app-to-salesf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I received an answer directly from Salesforce on this question and I wanted to share the details here for posterity.

> If a Salesforce direct AE sells to the same customer and specifies the same OrgID on the order, then the CRM licenses will be provisioned to the existing Org converting it into what we call Shared Org. This is a separate contract against the same Org.
>
> The key thing for the customer at this point is ensuring any OEM sold licenses are ONLY used with the Partner's application. Also, for the Partner, they may have contractual restrictions in their catalog preventing them from selling certain add-ons once it becomes a Shared Org.