# Salesforce: App Exchange: OEM: We are OEM partner. Can we sell our app to Salesforce existing customer where they are using CRM functionality?

Tags: appexchange, isv, partner, oem

Salesforce: App Exchange: OEM: We are OEM partner. Can we sell our app to Salesforce existing customer where they are using CRM functionality?

We have build product which does not required any Salesforce functionality like Sales or Service cloud but we have customer who already has an org using Sales cloud and they want to purchase our all on the top of it.

Can I sell OEM app in this case.
Is there additional contractual considerations?

Comment: _does not require any Salesforce functionality_ and _they want to purchase on top of (Sales Cloud)_ are contradictory terms, at least in plain (not contractual) language. It might be possible in terms of technology but there are lots of nuances. Consult your Legal and/or Salesforce OEM partner teams.

Comment: AFAIK an OEM partner (I work for one) can  sell to customers in one of two ways: org, user licenses and package licenses or just package licenses. If the customer already has an org with Salesforce CRM the OEM package can be added to that org for sure (I know we have customers like that).

Answer (score 1):

## Yes.

The limits between OEM and ISV are contractual. Selling an OEM license, you cannot expose base CRM objects in an OEM org. In exchange, you get to set the license fees for the licenses you sell, of which salesforce.com collects a percentage of, and you can brand your experience any way you like, to such an extent that users might not even realize they are running on Salesforce technology at all.

An ISV, by contrast, targets customers that already have CRM licenses. You don't negotiate the base license costs for their users, just for the number of licenses they want to assign to users for your app. It is safe to say that all OEM apps can also be licensed as ISV, because the OEM restrictions are stricter than the ISV restrictions. However, not all ISV apps will meet the contractual obligations of OEM agreements.